# Gtk3 window embedded with WebView looses maximize button on unmaximizing

Tags: python, webkit, pygtk, gtk3

Am coding in PyGtk, Gtk3 with WebKit.WebView and have encountered something weird.

On unmaximizing the window from maximized state, the window decorator looses maximize button and the window size becomes enormously large.

How can I remedy the problem???

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the WebView inside a [`GtkScrolledWindow`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkScrolledWindow.html):

```
scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scrolled.add(webview)
window.add(scrolled)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... but by now I have already switched to QtWebkit... :)